# How to prevent SharePoint from automatically adding the home page to global nav?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, branding

I have inherited a very large SharePoint 2010 Enterprise intranet with about 10 site collections (that I know of at this point). Needless to say, I'm finding a few odd problems/quirks on the site.

My current problem is that several site collections are using a fixed global nav bar (publishing on), which works fine, except that the name of the site collection gets added automatically to the left-most part of the nav bar (as the homepage).

For example when we are on the "Main" site collection, the word "Main" gets added to the leftmost item. On the "Communities" site collection, a link with the text "Communities" gets added, and so on.

Since this is a setup with multiple collections, what we really need is for the homepage (main site collection) to be the left-most link, but when I navigate to the particular site collection, the homepage for the collection gets added.

Does anyone know of an "out-of-the-box" way to fix this? I'm thinking I could find some way to set it to "display:none" using jQuery or something, but I'm hoping to do this without having to maintain custom code.

Comment: Have you tried changing the StartingNodeUrl within your master page (ControldId: TopNavigationDataSource) ?

Comment: No, I haven't. Surprised that would be necessary to fix something so basic. Do you have a link on how one might do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about any OOTB way to hide it, the simplest way would be to add a css to your custom css file or include the below CSS in the master page directly.

div.s4-tn ul.static > li:first-child {
    display: none;
}

Changing the navigation provider to hide the first node seems lot of work.

Comment: @Aveenav: Was really hoping that would work. Unfortunately, it eliminated the entire top nav bar. Not a bad start though.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your generated source for the top nav (use firebug or similiar)?

Comment: It looks like we are having the same problem but I've described it differently with a Screesnhot [Here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95047/sharepoint-2013-global-top-navigation-page-title-listed-as-home-but-disp)