# Sharepoint 2013 - Global (Top) Navigation - Page Title Listed As 'Home' but Displaying Name of Subsite

Tags: navigation, global-navigation

I hope someone can help answer this.

Page Title is Home and I want the First Top Nav Item to be 'Home'

If I change the Subsite Title - then it changes the title in the Top Nav on the HomePage to 'Home' - which I don't want.

I hope this is clear. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://bemusedbi.blogspot.com/2013/04/hiding-home-link-in-sharepoint-2013-top.html

/* deletes the top nav left side 'Home' button do not delete*/

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > a{
display: none !important;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > ul a{
display: block !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using CSS ':after' selector and 'content' property.

```
#DeltaTopNavigation ul#zz10_RootAspMenu > li.static > a > span > span:after {
  content: "Home";
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#DeltaTopNavigation ul#zz10_RootAspMenu > li.static > a > span > span {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

[image]

In the above image, you can see the highlighted text is "Lorem Ipsum Dolar" which we make it font-size: 0 and add content property "Home" to it's parent span tag.
You may have to adjust the CSS 'ul#zz10_RootAspMenu' to your id (use Firebug/IE tools to select elements and view hierarchy).

Comment: This is not correct. Please do not mark the questions as answered when they are really not.

Comment: you have to use the .root class of the ul rather than the #id because that number will change per page.